# How to write data in a file without replacing the existing data using cy.writeFile

Tags: cypress, writefile

I'm trying to save some data from API in a .json file using cy.writeFile method, but my code is replacing the existing data.
What I need is to add additional data.

```js
 cy.intercept('POST', 'http://viasphere.localhost/sites/datatable').as('response')
        cy.contains('Sortir').click()
        cy.wait('@response').get('@response').then(xhr => {
            console.log(xhr)
            let siteID = xhr.response.body.data[0].id
            let creationDate = xhr.response.body.data[0].created_at
            let RM = xhr.response.body.data[0].metal_rollout
            let clientGroup = xhr.response.body.data[0].client_contact_group

            cy.writeFile('SiteAPIdata.json', {siteID2: siteID})
```

After the run, the data existing inside the SiteAPIdata.json file is being replaced by the new data.
The SiteAPIdata.json file is located in cypress/fixtures/ folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to append the new data to the existing data, that can easily be accomplished by using `cy.readFile()` before writing.

```js
...
cy.readFile('SiteAPIdata.json').then((data) => {
  data.siteID = siteID;
  cy.writeFile('SiteAPIdata.json', data);
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but is there a more compact way to do it without creating a const, or reading the file?

Comment: After reading the cypress documentation found a more compact way without creating a new constant:
```js
        cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/SiteData.json').then(SiteData => {  
                SiteData.siteID = xhr.response.body.data[0].id,
                cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/SiteData.json', SiteData)
            })
```

Comment: I can edit my response to be closer to what works for you. Based on the question asked, I wouldn't have been able to know you wanted to update `siteID`, considering that your workaround was writing `{siteID2: siteID}`.